# From date should less than to date in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am doing date validation, i want my from date should less than to date in jquery validation plugin.

I have post my code.

```
            <form id="projectDetails" role="form" class="errormessage form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>profile/addprojectdetails" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group clearfix">
                <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Duration</label>
                <div class="p5 col-md-2 pull-left mr10">
                             <select id="from_month_attended" name="from_month"    class="small_input form-control">
                            <option value="0">Month</option>
                            <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
                            <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
                            <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
                            <option value="May">May</option>
                            <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
                            <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
                            <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
                            <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
                            <option value="Oct">oct</option>
                            <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
                            <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p5 col-md-2 pull-left">
                        <select id="from_year_attended" name="from_year" class="small_input form-control">
                        <option value="0">year</option>
                            <?php

                                for( $y=2014; $y>=1921; $y-- )
                                {
                                echo "<option value='".$y."'>".$y."</option>";
                                }

                             ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <span class="pull-left">-</span>
                         <div class="p5 col-md-2 pull-left">
                         <select id="to_month_attended" name="to_month" class="small_input form-control">
                            <option value="0">Month</option>
                            <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
                            <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
                            <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
                            <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
                            <option value="May">May</option>
                            <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
                            <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
                            <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
                            <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
                            <option value="Oct">oct</option>
                            <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
                            <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p5 col-md-2 pull-left" id="insertDateError">
                        <select onchange="attendYear();" id="to_year_attended" name="to_year" class="small_input form-control">
                        <option value="0">Year</option>
                            <?php

                                for( $y=2014; $y>=1921; $y-- )
                                {
                                echo "<option value='".$y."'>".$y."</option>";
                                }

                             ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
            </div>
       </form>
```

Script:

```
function attendYear(){
    var att_from_month=$('#from_month_attended').val();
    var att_from_year=$('#from_year_attended').val();
    var att_from = att_from_month+'-'+att_from_year;
    var att_to_month=$('#to_month_attended').val();
    var att_to_year=$('#to_year_attended').val();
    var att_to = att_to_month+'-'+att_to_year;
    if(att_from_month !=0 && att_from_year!=0 && att_to_month!=0 && att_to_year!=0)
    {
    var from = att_from;
    var to   = att_to;

    if ((new Date(from).getTime()) <= (new Date(to).getTime())) {
        document.getElementById("errordate").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("errordate").innerHTML = "Fromdate should less than todate";
    }
    }

}
```

I tried this code, its working fine in google chrome but its not working in firefox. Can any one help me what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple approach(obviously its not a better solution) and Add required rules and messages in your validator function.

```
var fromMonth= $('#duration_from_month').val();
var fromYear= $('#duration_from_year').val();
var toMonth= $('#duration_to_month').val();
var toYear= $('#duration_to_year').val();

if(toYear<fromYear){
....do something
}
else {
if(toMonth<fromMonth){
....do something
}
}
```